# Lookup Column of a List Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, lookup-column, column, sharepoint-fields

I have a requirement for a project site in SharePoint.
The Site will have:

- 1st List: a **Stakeholders List** with the **names** of people involved (people/group type) in the project and their **Project Role** (Roles: *"Manager" or "Simple stakeholder" or "Quality control"*)
- 2nd List: a List with only one item for **Project Details** of the specific project site.
  *Columns:*
  Project-Title  |  Managers  |  Simple-Stakeholders  |  Quality controllers

The Columns: "Managers, Simple-Stakeholders, Quality controllers" need to have the Names of stakeholders as in the first list.
***E.g. for the columns "Managers": display the names of those who have role=manager***

***--Example--***

**Items in Stakeholders List**
NAME: George  |  ROLE: Simple Stakeholder
NAME: Tom     |  ROLE: Manager
NAME: Mary    |  ROLE: Simple Stakeholder

**Project Details**
Project-title  |  Managers: Tom  |  Simple-Stakeholders: George; Mary

**Is this feasible?**
- An option is to use Managed metadata for Project-Role, but I don't know if it's possible to retrieve in column Managers, the names where the term is "manager".
- An other is to use Lookup columns.

Thanks a lot for your time!

---

A Thread with the same issue:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6dc78246-4963-40c7-9b81-74a4b609c6e0/if-more-than-value-is-returned-only-the-first-value-will-be-used?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

Answer (score 0):

I have some solution for this case, it just use tool which SP support.

1. Use workflow, when user create/update item in **Stakeholders** list, it will also copy item into the **Project Details** list. It will automatically copy and user don't need to do anything in **Project Details**
2. Use Managed metadata like you say, and the items in **Stakeholders** you must create in term set of site. Then, the user will choose items in this term and updated in **Project Details**. So, this will be manually.